# Responsive Youtube embed causing Share It buttons to be placed in wrong place in Wordpress

Tags: css, youtube, wordpress, responsive-design

I have made my youtube embeds responsive using this css

```
.video-container {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 30px; /* IE6 workaround*/
    padding-bottom: 57.25%; /* 16/9 */
    overflow: hidden;
}
.video-container iframe,  
.video-container object,  
.video-container embed {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

It keeps giving me a problem with the share it function of the jetpack wordpress plugin. The share it buttons float over the video instead of being displayed below the video.

Anyone know how I can solve the css?